# Format datetime field as MON-YYYY in python pandas & ignore nulls

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I have a python pandas dataframe "df" as below -

```
      NAME  SETID   VENDOR_ID vendor_created_date
0  Vendor1     SD          93 2002-11-22 11:04:33
1  Vendor2     SD          94 2003-08-09 11:40:59
2  Service1    SD          95 2003-10-31 10:29:21
3  Vendor3     SD          01                 NaT
4  Vendor4     SD          02                 NaT
```

The `vendor_created_date` is of the format `datetime64[ns]`.

Now I want to create a new field called `fomatted_date` where the `vendor_created_date` field values should be in the format `MON-YYYY` & I want to delete the rows with `NaT` in the date field.

Can you please give me directions?

Comment: Why is there a [tag:r] tag here? Are you looking for a solution in R too?

Comment: Anyway, I'm detagging this for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this the format you wanted?

Basically we can drop the `NaN` rows first and then call `apply` and use `datetime.strftime` to apply a new format:

```
In [24]:

df = df.dropna()
df['fomatted_date'] = df['vendor_created_date'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x,'%b-%Y'))
df
Out[24]:
           NAME SETID  VENDOR_ID vendor_created_date fomatted_date
Index                                                             
0       Vendor1    SD         93 2002-11-22 11:04:33      Nov-2002
1       Vendor2    SD         94 2003-08-09 11:40:59      Aug-2003
2      Service1    SD         95 2003-10-31 10:29:21      Oct-2003
```

Answer (score 0):

There are severals ways to do it.

One way would be to use a regular expression (`re` module) to get search for a known pattern and replace it with the desired output.

Another way would be to use the `datetime` module and convert it to the desired format with datetime.datetime.strftime.